# How to define a circle filled with several slanted lines?

Tags: symbols

How to define a circle filled with several slanted lines as in the following picture?

[image]

Note that we already have `\bigcirc` in tex. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw the symbol using Ti*k*Z and then use the `scalerel` package to make it the same size as `\bigcirc`. You can adjust the thickness, distance and angle of the lines (as well as color and other things).

[image]

If you plan to use this symbol many times in a document you might want to put it in a `savebox` to reduce compiling time.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, scalerel}
\usetikzlibrary {patterns.meta}

\newcommand{\slantcirc}{\mathrel{\scalerel*{\tikz{
    \draw[line width=1.4pt, pattern={Lines[angle=45, distance={.6pt}, line width=.3pt]}] circle[radius=5mm];
}}{\bigcirc}}}

\begin{document}

$A\slantcirc B_{A\slantcirc B_{A\slantcirc B}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good solution! Thanks!